# Why does the calculation for y-value (when converting from lat/long to a Mercator x,y) involve the width of the map?

Tags: coordinate-system, mapping, mathematics, mercator

I have been looking into converting latitude and longitude into x and y coordinates. [This link (first answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14329691/convert-latitude-longitude-point-to-a-pixels-x-y-on-mercator-projection) provides a perfect answer for me, but I am wondering *why* it works.

I have figured out why most of it works, but this part:

```
y = (mapHeight/2)-(mapWidth*mercN/(2*PI));
```

Confuses me a little bit. I assume that `mapHeight/2` is there to find the equator so we can find the y-value in relation to how big the map is.

But why is it `(mapWidth*mercN/(2*π))`? And why are they subtracted from each other? Shouldn't `mapWidth` only be used for finding the x-value?

I suspect it has something to do with how the map is essentially an unwrapped cylinder from the expansion of a sphere ([which is what Mercator's projection is](https://personal.math.ubc.ca/%7Eisrael/m103/mercator/mercator.html)), but I am struggling to see how the width of the map should affect the y-value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the comments to that answer, it seems as though the equation posted is wrong. It is not supposed to be `mapWidth`, but `mapHeight`. Not only does this make more sense (as the width of the map should not play a role in the y-value on the Mercator projection), but it gives more accurate answers as well. The formula should be

```
y = (mapHeight/2)-(mapHeight*mercN/(2*PI))
```

rather than

```
y = (mapHeight/2)-(mapWidth*mercN/(2*PI))
```